# Match all square brackets with preg_match_all`

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match multiple square bracket tags in a string to extract them from the string.

For example:

```
$string = 'Request: [CODE]sksdjdiwjwdwdkw[/CODE] Response: [CODE]sksdjdiwjwdwdkw[/CODE]';
```

`preg_match_all('/\[CODE\](.*)\[\/CODE\]/',$string)` matches everything between the first `[CODE]` and last `[/CODE]`.

Does anyone have a idea on how the expression are suppost to look like?

Answer (score 3):

Try making your match non-greedy:

```
preg_match_all('/\[CODE\](.*?)\[\/CODE\]/',$string)
                          ^^^
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy :) Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @Gomer: if this answer solved your problem then accept it! Click on the "green mark" next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.*` (faster than non-greedy)

```
preg_match_all('/\[CODE\]([^\[]+)\[\/CODE\]/',$string);
```